# How to obtain specificity and negative predictive value from Scikit-learn for multiclass classification?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, reporting, precision-recall

Currently, scikit-learn's default classification report (`sklearn.metrics.classification_report` - [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html)) does not include specificity and negative predictive value (NPV).

Hence, I made my own classification report function:

```
def custom_classification_report(y_true, y_pred):
    tp, fn, fp, tn = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred).ravel()
    acc = (tp+tn)/(tp+tn+fp+fn)
    sen = (tp)/(tp+fn)
    sp = (tn)/(tn+fp)
    ppv = (tp)/(tp+fp)
    npv = (tn)/(tn+fn)
    f1 = 2*(sen*ppv)/(sen+ppv)
    fpr = (fp)/(fp+tn)
    tpr = (tp)/(tp+fn)
    return (    '2X2 confusion matrix:', ['TP', tp, 'FP', fp, 'FN', fn, 'TN', tn],
                'Accuracy:', round(acc, 3),
                'Sensitivity/Recall:', round(sen, 3),
                'Specificity:', round(sp, 3),
                'PPV/Precision:', round(ppv, 3),
                'NPV:', round(npv, 3),
                'F1-score:', round(f1, 3),
                'False positive rate:', round(fpr, 3),
                'True positive rate:', round(tpr, 3),
            )

def auc_roc(y_true, y_pred_score):
    return ('AUC-ROC:', round(roc_auc_score(y_true, y_pred_score), 3))

def avg_precision(y_true, y_pred_score, target_name):
    return ('Average precision:', round(average_precision_score(y_true, y_pred_score, pos_label=target_name), 3))
    tpr = (tp)/(tp+fn)
    return (    '2X2 confusion matrix:', ['TP', tp, 'FP', fp, 'FN', fn, 'TN', tn],
                'Accuracy:', round(acc, 3),
                'Sensitivity/Recall:', round(sen, 3),
                'Specificity:', round(sp, 3),
                'PPV/Precision:', round(ppv, 3),
                'NPV:', round(npv, 3),
                'F1-score:', round(f1, 3),
                'False positive rate:', round(fpr, 3),
                'True positive rate:', round(tpr, 3),
            )

def auc_roc(self, y_true, y_pred_score):
    return ('AUC-ROC:', round(roc_auc_score(y_true, y_pred_score), 3))

def avg_precision(self, y_true, y_pred_score, target_name):
    return ('Average precision:', round(average_precision_score(y_true, y_pred_score, pos_label=target_name), 3))
```

It works fine while I am using it for binary class classification -

```
print('>> Custom classification report:\n', custom_classification_report(y_test, predicted_labels), '\n')
```

When I used the same line of code `print('>> Custom classification report:\n', custom_classification_report(y_test, predicted_labels), '\n')` for multiclass classification, it gives an error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)`. Why is that, and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions of the confusion matrix are dependent on the number of classes you have.

In the 2x2 case, you will return the expected four (tn, fp, fn, tp). However, in the multi-class case you will return a n_class * n_class matrix.

Try for example:

````
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
test = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,]
pred = [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,0]
confusion_matrix(test, pred)```
````

which generates:
 `array([[3, 1, 0], [0, 3, 1], [1, 1, 2]])`

... a 3 x3 matrix. So your function can't unpack those 9 values into 4.

If you want the four values, you need to take one class of interest (e.g. class 1) and then run a 2x2 confusion matrix of that class versus all the other classes combined.

One other note, I think that the confusion_matrix function scores are returned in a slightly different order than you have specified above (it's tn, fp, fn, tp on https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html).